# Center point of parallelogram of two 2D vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

I have two 2D vectors starting at $(0,0)$: $a(x_1,y_1)$ and $b(x_2,y_2)$ and I need to calculate the coordinates of the center point of the parallelogram that they "create". Does anyone know the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is $$C({x_1+x_2\over 2},{y_1+y_2\over 2})$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

In general(also in $\mathbb{R^3}$) given 2 vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ their **midpoint** $\vec M$ is given by: $$\vec M=\frac{\vec A+\vec B}{2}$$

More in general a point $\vec P$ **along the line** through $\vec A$ and $\vec B$  is given by:

$$\vec P=(1-\lambda)\cdot\vec A+\lambda\cdot \vec B \quad with \quad \lambda \in\mathbb{R}$$

NOTE

$\lambda=0 \implies \vec P = \vec A$

$\lambda=\frac12 \implies \vec P = \vec M$

$\lambda=1 \implies \vec P = \vec B$